# Evaluate regression quality using repeated values

Tags: regression

To determine a regression from a set of variables, ex: Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4 and the target T, what is it wrong if an important set of examples contain the same values in Var1, Var2, Var3 and different in var4? overfitting? The best set of examples would be the one containing var variables with different values?